# Group homomorphism from rationals to integers

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have to find all the 
$$ 
Hom_g(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z})
. 
$$

In the exercise, it doesn't say which are the operations for the groups, so I assumed, it had to be in both cases the regular sum. What I thought, and I'm not completely sure it's right, is that there only is one $$f\in Hom_g(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}),$$ which is the trivial case, f(q)=0. I did the following:

Since $$f\in Hom_g(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}).$$ it follows that, f(0)=0 and f(p+q)=f(p)+f(q). Suppose that exists, and $$p\in\mathbb{Q}$$ such that $$0<f(p)=n\in\mathbb{Z}$$ So, if n is odd, then n=f(p)=f(p/2 + p/2) = f(p/2) + f(p/2) , then f(p/2)=n/2 absurd. If n is not odd, then, let's say in it's prime composition, the power of 2 y m, so $$f(p/2^m)\notin\mathbb{Z}$$

Then, it has to be f(p)=0, for all p in Q. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks good (basically). But why require $n > 0$? That choice shouldn't matter. Just assume $n \ne 0$. Of course, since you have additive inverses, you can force $n > 0$ if you think that makes the proof more clear.

Comment: You can avoid the cases by asking what $f\left(\frac{p}{2n}\right)$ can be, when $n=f(p)\neq 0$.

Comment: good idea, works with any denominator, not only 2

Comment: Thanks. I was feeling like it should've been wrong, but i feel better now :P